# How to reduce the distance between options in dropdown in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I m binding values dynamically in to the dropdown using ionic 2 and here allare working good except space between the options and and unable to set header name on the dropdown below is my code & although im using using **interface="pop over"** it is also not working & made changes in main.css and .scss file also but nothing works

```
<ion-select  #sectionSelect [(ngModel)]="location" (ionChange)="onChange(sectionSelect.text)" interface="popover" placeholder=" " hidden>
        <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of Locations" [value]="opt.LocationId">{{opt.LocationName}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

[image: i am getting dropdown like the below format there i unable to remove or put name in header like Gender & unable to reduce the spaces between options]

i am getting dropdown like the below format there i unable to remove or put name in header like Gender & unable to reduce the spaces between options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ion-list and ion-item as mentioned in the document. [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio)

Extract from Component

```
selectedDropdown : any;
  dropDown : any = [];
 this.dropDown=[
    "100 - BISCUIT - 546156",
    "252 - CHOCO - 185268",
    "131 - CANDY - 478215"
]
this.selectedDropdown=this.dropDown[0];
  }
```

Template

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Dishes</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedDropdown">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let val of dropDown" value= {{val}}>{{val}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: but is there any possibility fo removing header & reducing the spacing between the options

Comment: remove ion-label from the template so you will not get header. Reducing space between the option is unnecessary if you want you can try it in console.

Comment: Mark this as accepted answer if this had helped you.